# Laravel 8: Multiple Select Option Does Not Send Data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, select-options

I have two tables at db, one of them is named `users` which simply contains user information of website and the other one is `tags` which contains some hashtags that users can choose from them.

(just like Stackoverflow that a user can select multiple tags such as *php*, *javascript* & etc)

So in order to make this relationship between these two, I added this to `User` model:

```
public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class);
    }
```

And also this one to `Tag` model:

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
```

And here is the select option on blade, and users can select multiple tags from db:

```
<select class="form-control BSinaBold" name="skills[]" id="skills" multiple>
    @foreach(\App\Models\Tag::all() as $tag)
        <option value="{{ $tag->id }}" {{ in_array($tag->id , Auth::user()->tags->pluck('id')->toArray()) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $tag->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Then at the Controller, I added this in order to update data at `tags` table:

```
public function update(Request $request, $profile)
{
    $validate_data = Validator::make($request->all(),[
        'job' => 'nullable',
        'stackoverflow' => 'nullable',
        'github' => 'nullable',
        'instagram' => 'nullable',
        'linkedin' => 'nullable',
        'website' => 'nullable',
        'location' => 'nullable',
        'skills' => 'array',
    ]);

    $user = User::findOrFail($profile);

    $user->update([
        'job' => request('job'),
        'stackoverflow' => request('stackoverflow'),
        'github' => request('github'),
        'instagram' => request('instagram'),
        'linkedin' => request('linkedin'),
        'website' => request('website'),
        'location' => request('location'),
    ]);

    $user->tags()->sync(request('skills'));

    $user->save();

    return view('profile');
}
```

And it works fine and perfect but the only problem is this line, that does not sync data at `tags` table:

`$user->tags()->sync(request('skills'));`

So I tried debugging and I found out that `request('skills')` is EMPTY!

So the question is, why it does not send any data to the Controller?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you define your model relation wrong.
Tag model should be:

```
      public function user()
      {
         return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
      }
```

and the User Model relations:

```
      public function tags()
       {
          return $this->hasMany(Tag::class);
       }
```

If you aim to establish a one-to-many relation.